# storage() is unavailable use object construction FIRStorage() and database() is unavailable use object construction FIRDatabase()

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods, firebase-storage

When I put the code:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

I get the error:

> database() is unavailable use object construction FIRDatabase()

And with:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
```

I get the error:

> storage() is unavailable use object construction FIRStorage()

I've added `import FirebaseDatabase` and `import FirebaseStorage` and have added them to my pod file and i have Xcode 7.2.1 and swift 2.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so assuming your're using the newest version of swift and firebase pods, it's now written as Database instead of FIRDatabse and Storage instead of FIRStorage.

Furthermore, your podfile needs to have

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

for what you're doing.

Make sure that when you close, you save the Podfile and then run podinstall. Furthermore, its important that you use the .xcworkspace not the .xcodeproj after installing.

Lastly, I think you should only need

```
import Firebase
```

because it includes database and storage.

Comment: oh sorry when someone edited they removed the version of swift i was using which is 2 and when doing Database and storage it say use of unresolved identifier Database and Storage

Answer (score 1):

First one is import like this:

```
import Firebase
```

Then create an object by:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
```

After latest release, `FIRDatabase` changed to `Database`

Comment: for got to make sure he edit included that I'm running on swift 2 and i already imported Firebase and when doing let ref = Database.database().reference() i get unresolved identifier Database